# normal distribution - nationalized bank

Tags: normal-distribution

A nationalized bank has found that the daily balance available in its saving bank accounts follows a normal distribution with a mean of Rs. 500 and a standard deviation of Rs. 50. The percentage of savings account holders who maintain an average daily balance more than Rs. 500 is _______________.

As it is a normal distribution, values more than mean will have 0.5 probability of occurrence. So can I say directly there will be 50% of saving account holders who maintain an average daily balance more than than Rs. 500.

Comment: Yeah, that seems right

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this follows from the fact that the Normal distribution is symmetric with respect to the mean.